# Query double nested array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, nested

I am trying to query a BigQuery table that contains multiple nested arrays of records.

The table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZMsv.png)

So I do have a profile ID, and for one single ID, I have multiple Collaborator_Type and Permission.
For every single Collaborator_Type I have an array of Params.name and Params.value.

How is it possible to build a query that would produce as final output similar to this:

profileId ---- Collaborator_Type ----Collaborator.Permission ----primary_event ---- billable...and followed by every single field in Params.name as the title of the column and corresponding filed in Params.value as the result in the column)

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: It is helpful for accessibility to avoid images of code/structures if you can help it. Try to create your data table as a formatted ASCII table. Also, you should add a description for your image.

Comment: there are plenty of similar (if not identical) questions answered already here on SO. Search for `pivot` for example

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to extract them manually with subqueries:

```
SELECT
  profileId,
  Collaborator_Type,
  Collaborator_Permission,
  (SELECT value FROM t.Params WHERE name = 'primary_event') AS primary_event,
  (SELECT value FROM t.Params WHERE name = 'billable') AS billable
FROM mytable t
```

Comment: I feel, this is not going to work. the simples fix is to use `FROM t.Params` instead of `FROM Params` and obviously add alias `t` to `FROM mytable`, so it will be `FROM mytable t`